Policeman pursuing woman with baby on spaceship
Looking for a recent SF novel where the
protagonist is policeman pursuing woman with baby. They live on the inside of a giant spaceship/planet that is starting to fall apart.
Read as a Kindle book within the past 5 to 10 years.
Policeman starts our pursuing woman, but joins with her when he catches up to her. The woman is either pregnant or has a baby with her.
The last humans are living inside enormous ship that is starting to break apart, which it does at the end.
The policeman and woman steal a car and take off across a desert. they make it to the outer edge of the ship just as it is falling apart.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover?
